# Hive select outputs null values

Tags: select, hive

I get the select output as null for the following Hive table.

```
Describe studentdetails;

clustername             string                     
schemaname              string                     
tablename               string                     
primary_key             map<string,int>            
schooldata              struct<alternate_aliases:string,application_deadline:bigint,application_deadline_early_action:string,application_deadline_early_decision:bigint,calendaring_system:string,fips_code:string,funding_type:string,gender_preference:string,iped_id:bigint,learning_environment:string,mascot:string,offers_open_admission:boolean,offers_rolling_admission:boolean,region:string,religious_affiliation:string,school_abbreviation:string,school_colors:string,school_locale:string,school_term:string,short_name:string,created_date:bigint,modified_date:bigint,percent_students_outof_state:float>   from deserializer   
deletedind              boolean                    
truncatedind            boolean                    
versionid               bigint                     

select * from studentdetails limit 3;
```

**Output :**

```
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

I have used the following properties while creating the table.

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
```

And the following properties while selecting the data.

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
ADD JAR s3://emr/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.0.jar;
```

Comment: Do you have a question? If yes, make it explicit. And also display the original JSON. Plus, take care of formatting your question properly...

Comment: Please add the results of `show create table studentdetails;` and some data sample

Comment: I had the same issue and it was because I had to specify the property `lines terminated by` in the `create external table` script because it was different than the end of line of the files.

Comment: @DavidEspart I would high recommend instead of using `SELECT *` use specific column.why I asked about specific column because it could be output for one column in case if you have txt file with \t and defined the table , delimeter. Also it would be better to use in the such question `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>;` to review your scheme issue. 

how did you insert data to the table? if you were using text format it should be splitted like you defined in the table properties on create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments, I have found the solution for this.

The issue was that the column name in my json file and the column name that i used while creating the table was different.

When i synched the column names between the Hive table and the Json File the issue was resolved.

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN